# Dismissing modal view controller after sending email with MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have a view controller presented modally to let people sign up for a newsletter that then calls `MFMailComposer`. Once the mail is sent, I want to be able to dismiss the modal view controller after I click **Send** on the email window. Is this possible?

This was incorrectly marked a duplicate because my code is structured as follows:

CustomViewController calls ModalViewController
ModalViewController calls MailComposer
After user clicks send the ModalViewController needs to be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss the controller in `mailComposeController(_:didFinishWith:error:)` after you checked that the `MFMailComposeResult` is `sent`.

```swift
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)

    if result == .sent {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Remember that you should set the delegate of the mail compose view controller and your view controller should conform to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol:

```swift
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    fileprivate var mailComposeVc: MFMailComposeViewController!
    [...]

    func someFunc() {
        mailComposeVc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct way is to switch the result inside the completion handler of the dismiss method

Comment: @LeoDabus Switching is not mandatory if the OP wants to handle just one result, although it can be useful for debugging purposes. Also, I am interested in what advantages does handling the dismissal of the view controller inside the completion handler of the dismiss method have.

Comment: It only executes the code once the dismiss animation is complete

Comment: @LeoDabus Of course, that's obvious. I'm just asking whether waiting for the animation is necessarily a good thing.

Comment: It is just about displaying it properly

Comment: Thank you the if result == .sent portion is what I needed.